# Can the Google Visualization SDK for making pie charts be used in Android mobile App?

Tags: google-visualization, pie-chart

I am looking at the Google Visualization: Pie Chart user guide and it looks really cool.  The question remains, can it be used by an Android or IOS mobile device?

Comment: The demos in the documentation (and linked fiddles) seem to work in Chrome on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2.

Comment: @drs9222 are you viewing with a browser on your mobile or have them compiled into an Android APK?  My question might be ambiguous, but I am asking as an SDK for Android app development.

Comment: I just looked at the demos on the website through the Chrome browser on my phone because I was curious to see if they would work.

Comment: @drs9222 that is what I thought.  I will wait for the answer I intended to ask (and I will edit the question for clarity).  Thanks for your response.